# ¿UNITY: Cómo hacer que detecte la colision de dos objetos de un color determinado?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tengo un escenario con 1 objeto donde colisiona con dos objetos, el primero color azul , el segundo color azul.

**Me gustaría saber cómo hacer que detecte cuando ambos son del mismo color haga una determinada acción**. Dicha acción ya la tengo clara, y la colisión también la tengo programada, pero que detecte si son del mismo color... no.

¿ cómo?

colision:

```
public class Colision : MonoBehaviour {

    //public GameObject HaloPrefab; // empty with halo applied to it...

    public Text points;


    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){


        if ( col.gameObject.name == "Cube") {

            col.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Lo que hago es que si colisiona desaparezca el objeto, pero necesito que haga eso si ambos son del mismo color. 
        }




        if ( col.gameObject.name == "Cube(Clone)") {

            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);


        }     
}
```

Por si sirve de algo, el objeto que puede colisionar le puedes cambiar el color, y lo hago asi, **y sí que funciona** :

```
public class ChangeColor : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material[] materials;
    public Renderer rend;

    private int index = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        rend = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        rend.enabled = true;

    }

    public void Update() {
        if (materials.Length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            index += 1;

            if (index == materials.Length + 1) {
                index = 1; 
            }
            print (index);

            rend.sharedMaterial = materials [index - 1];                        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Si, tal como parece, el color viene determinado por el material y ambos game objects comparten ese material, puedes hacer lo siguiente (código no probado):

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube"
        && col.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial == GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial)
    {
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    if ( col.gameObject.name == "Cube(Clone)")
    {
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    } 
}
```